# Check to see if currently connected to work network (ldap server)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Firstly, I apologize if i have raised this incorrectly or not quite to the rules. It is my first post.

Can someone please help with my issue.

I have an web application that is fully functioning and authorizes the user.

my problem is that i want to add a check when the site loads to see if the PC is currently connected to the work network. EG. when at home and not connected via VPN I want to redirect to an error page stating not connected to the AD Domain Network.

Currently the app just crashes with exception of "ldap server cannot be reached".

I hope this makes sense.

CODE ADDED

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Public Class Gen

Dim DomUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current

Public ADUser As String = AppSettings("DomainPrefix").ToString & DomUser.SamAccountName
Public ADEmail As String = DomUser.EmailAddress
Public ADForname As String = DomUser.GivenName
Public ADSurname As String = DomUser.Surname
Public ADFullName As String = ADForname & " " & ADSurname

Public wi As WindowsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity

End Class
```

Culprit line is

```
Dim DomUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current
```

Comment: If it crashes with the specified exception then its telling you something, need to handle that instead of the entire app crashing, just handle it gracefully with `Try`.. `Catch` block...

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that but where the code is it is not in a sub or function so cannot use try catch. it is inside a class.

`Dim DomUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current`

Comment: Enclose the [MCVE] that demonstrates what you meant. This needs to be wrapped up in a function or in parlance, method of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to use the proper OOP paradigm.

```
Public Function CheckLDAP() As Boolean
    Dim DomUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal
    Dim blnLDAPOk As Boolean = False
    Try
       DomUser = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current
       blnLDAPOk = True
    Catch ex as Exception
       ' Perhaps Throw an exception to be handled
    End Try
    Return blnLDAPOk
End Function
```

From the class `Gen`, instantiate the class

```
Dim gLDAP = New Gen
If (gLDAP.CheckLDAP()) Then
    ' We are in
Else
    ' Whoops, no LDAP found
End If
```

Comment: You are a legend. Thank you so much. i have it working as i want now. Cant thank you enough.